# datatable.js ajax livereload after n seconds

Tags: javascript, datatables-1.10

I want to reload a [datatable](https://github.com/guinslym/flask_sqlite_datatable_js_and_live_update_data/blob/main/templates/index.html) after n amount of seconds.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#table_id').DataTable( {
            "ajax": "http://192.168.1.134:8000/api/",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "city" },
            ],
            
        }
            
        );
} );
    
setInterval(function(){
    table.ajax.reload(null, false);
      },5000);
```

But the total row in the table keeps being the same.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer in the [Documenation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

```
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "http://192.168.1.134:8000/api/",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "city" },
    ],
    
}
    
);

setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload(); // user paging is not reset on reload
}, 30000 );
```